# How to make buttons with icons above the text

Tags: html, css

The CSS for the buttons is this:

```
.physician:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("../theImages/ste.png") no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 52px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.urgentcare:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("../theImages/ug.png") no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 52px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    /*margin-left: 10%;*/
}
```

What I am trying to do is make all the buttons appear like the physicians button, the icon centered horizontally above the text which is also centered horizontally.

Button css:

```
button:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("../theImages/ste.png") no-repeat;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 52px;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
button {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #eee;
    color: #515151;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 21px 34px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.21, rgb(203,203,203)), color-stop(0.58, rgb(227,226,226)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(203,203,203) 21%, rgb(227,226,226) 58%);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3) /* glass edge */, inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5) /* top highlight */, inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5) /* bottom shadow */;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
button::-moz-focus-inner, a.button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
button:hover, a.button:hover {
    background: #cbcbcb;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:active, a.button:active {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 22px 34px 20px; /* Bump down text */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-shadow: none;
}
.red {
    background: #e1001a;
    color: #fff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.21, rgb(192,0,22)), color-stop(0.58, rgb(226,0,26)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(192,0,22) 21%, rgb(226,0,26) 58%);
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.red:hover {
    background: #cb0018;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.red:active {
    background: #ae0014;
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: have you  tried : `:before {content:url(myicon);display:block;margin:auto;}` ?

Comment: Can you show the css for the container element?

Comment: Try `.urgentcare:before { width: 100% }` and remove padding/margin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were almost there, instead of inline-block, make the image a block element:

```
.physician:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url("../theImages/ste.png") no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 52px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4YEW5/4/)

Comment: I will test it out and update. the above code will make every button like the Physicians button?